# Is there a bitcoin api?

Tags: development

Sorry if my question sounds silly, I get downvoted for some reason everytime I ask it. I just need some help

Today I saw the "richest bitcoin wallets" chart and I was inspired to program the same thing, it's interesting for me to know how this type of research is done. I want to be able to look into blockchain data by means of code and perform some queries (I guess?) to sort addresses starting from wealthiest. Also I want to get transactions data to analyze moves of traders

And, of course, I tried to google what I want to do but unfortunately, I was unable to find anything on that topic!

Can someone please point me the right direction? I can't find find out from where to start

Comment: This may help: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/11459/51948

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [many](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api).

If we define an Applications Programming Interface (API) as any kind of software interface between computers or programs then the following apply.

1. **[Bitcoin network protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation)**. You can write software to use this to obtain blockchain related information from any other Bitcoin node.
2. **Remote Procedure Calls (RPC)**. Many full-node implementations provide an RPC service. For example [Bitcoin Core RPC](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/). Other implementations may have their ownAPI. For example Electrum's [JSONRPC](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsonrpc.html). There is no guarantee that different software provides the same or even similar RPC API.
3. **Command Line interface (CLI)**. Although probably  designed with interactive use in mind, these can be used in scripts or invoked from compiled programs and thus constitute a kind of API. For example [Bitcoin Core CLI](https://www.kompulsa.com/bitcoin-cli-commands-and-api-methods/) - though I expect the RPC interface is preferable in most non-interactive cases.
4. **Web service APIs** provided by major Bitcoin related services. For example [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/api). This includes some Cryptocurrency Exchanges. It may be that these require registration and may be rate-limited for people who don't pay a subscription or otherwise have a business relationship.